# Array Preallocation Performance Decrease

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, primes

I have the following JavaScript function which calculates the number of primes <= `n`:

```
function F(n) {
  var i = 0, a = 3, b = 1, p = [2], s = 2, l = 0;

  while (a <= n) {
    s = p[i];
    if (a % s) {
      if (b < s || i === l) {
        p[++l] = a;
      } else {
        ++i;
        continue;
      }
    }
    b = Math.sqrt(a += 2) | 0;
    i = 0;
  }

  return l + 1 - (n < 2);
}
```

This currently works, and when run in node 5.5 it can calculate primes less than 10^8 in around 29.9 seconds. I want to optimize it however, and one of the things I thought of is to preallocate the array length. However, all methods I've tried for such have only increased the run time.

One thing I tried was to set `p.length` to the approximate number of primes I would be dealing with. I added the following line below the `var` declaration line:

```
p.length = n / (Math.log(n) - 1) | 0
```

But this brought the run time up by 1.5 seconds on 10^8. I also tried changing the array declaration to `new Array(n / (Math.log(n) - 1) | 0)`, and even tried using some of the new typed arrays like `new Uint32Array(n / (Math.log(n) - 1) | 0)`), but to no avail.

[JSPerf tests](https://jsperf.com/preallocating-array) seem to indicate that there should be a significant performance boost, but I'm only seeing a loss. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The JSPerf example uses a string array. Strings can't be stored in the array directly, they need a pointer indirection. My suspicion would be that a pure integer array (no undefined or null values) is handled as a special case that's even faster than "general" arrays. This doesn't explain why there is no improvement with Unit32Array though. Did you try Int32Array, too?

Comment: @StefanHaustein I did, and neither were good. `new Uint32Array(n/(Math.log(n)-1)|0)` brings it up to 35.5 seconds, and `new Int32Array(n/(Math.log(n)-1)|0)` does 32.7